# problem with array in C

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, pointers

I'm a programming student and I don't understand what is the problem with this code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void merge(int a[], int low, int high, int mid){
        int i, j, k, c[50];
        i=low;
        j=mid+1;
        k=low;
        while((i<=mid)&&(j<=high)){
            if(a[i]<a[j]){
                c[k]=a[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            } //end if
        else{
            c[k]=a[j];
            k++;
            j++;
            } //end else
        } //end while
        while(i<=mid){
            c[k]=a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        } //end while
        while(j<=high){
            c[k]=a[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        } //end while
        for(i=low;i<k;i++){
            a[i]=c[i];
        } //end for
    } //end merge()

    int mergesort(int a[], int low, int high){
        int mid;
        if(low<high){
            mid=(low+high)/2;
            mergesort(a,low,mid);
            mergesort(a,mid+1,high);
            merge(a,low,high,mid);
        } //end if
        return(0);
    } //end mergesort()

    int main(){
        int i, n, arr[100];
        do{
            scanf("%d", &n);
            if(n == 0)
                break;
            else{
                for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
                    mergesort(arr, 0, n);
                } //end for
            } //end else
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                printf("%d\n", &arr[i]);
        }while(n != 0); //end while
    } // end main()
```

And terminal shows me the following mistake

```
ej.c: In function ‘main’:
ej.c:60:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

The purpose of this program is to show a sorted array.

Comment: Tell us what this line is supposed to do in your own words, as much detail as possible: `printf("%d\n", &arr[i]);`

Answer (score 9):

Here:

```
 printf("%d\n", &arr[i]);
```

It should be

```
 printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
```

because you want to print the actual element of the array  `arr[i]`, and not its address `&arr[i]`.

---

Notice the difference between `scanf` and `printf` . In `scanf` you are supposed to provide the address ([explanation, why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893615/why-scanf-must-take-the-address-of-operator)), while in `printf` the actual value.

Answer (score 5):

```
printf("%d\n", &arr[i]);
```

`arr` is an array of integers
`arr[i]` is an integer
`&arr[i]` is a pointer

The `printf` specifier `"%d"` 'wants' an integer, not a pointer. Try

```
printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the `&` in the `scanf()` line; you do not need it in the `printf()` line.

You pass the address of the variable to `scanf()`; you pass the value `arr[i]` to `printf()`.

---

```
scanf("%d", &arr[i]);     // Correct

printf("%d\n", &arr[i]);  // Incorrect
printf("%d\n", arr[i]);   // Correct
```

> Would you explain why?

With `scanf()`, the function needs to modify the variables in the calling function, but since C passes arguments by value, that won't work; therefore, you have to pass pointers to the variables so that `scanf()` can write to the variables via the pointer.

By contrast, when you are printing the values, the pass-by-value mechanism is perfect; you supply the value to be printed, and `printf()` cannot accidentally modify the variable in the calling function. The `&` is the 'address of' operator, of course. To print a simple integer (such as `i`), you'd write `printf("%d\n", i);`, wouldn't you?  The same applies to arrays: `arr[i]` is an integer value like `i` is an integer value.  So, to pass the integer value to `printf()`, write:

```
printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
```

Comment: sorry.. would you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Well the warning says it all, `&arr[i]` is not an int but a pointer to an int. Did you intend `arr[i]` instead?

Answer (score 1):

In your `printf` near the end, you have

```
printf("%d\n", &arr[i]);
```

`arr[i]` is an `int`; `&arr[i]` is a pointer to it.

Lose the `&`.