# Program crashes when I try to move my player across the screen on a simple map in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

```
    int main()
    {
        int size, x, y, test = 1;
        printf("How big is your map? ");
        scanf("%d", &size);
        char map[size][size], move;
        int row = size/2, col = size/2;
        for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
        { //gives null value to everything in the board except for the player
            for(y = 0; y < size; y++)
            {
                map[x][y] = 'X';
            }
        }
        while(test != 0)
        {
            scanf("%d", &test);
            for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
            {
                for(y = 0; y < size; y++)
                    if (x == row && y == col)
                    {
                        printf("O");
                        map[row][col] = 'O';
                    }
                    else
                        printf("%c", map[x][y]);
                    printf("\n");
            }
//
// Everything runs completely fine until this point,
// after I type either W, A, S, or D, the program crashes
// and gives me an insanely high return value.
// I have no idea what I did wrong, and any insight would be extremely appreciated.
//
            printf("Use W, A, S, D to move around.");
            map[row][col] = 'X'; //set the old player location to null.
            while(x != 0)
            {
                scanf(" %c", move);
                switch(move)
                {
                    case 'w': 
                    case 'W': row -= 1; x = 0; break;
                    case 's':
                    case 'S': row += 1; x = 0; break;
                    case 'a':
                    case 'A': col -= 1; x = 0; break;
                    case 'd':
                    case 'D': col += 1; x = 0; break;
                    default: printf("Invalid input, try again.");
                }
            }
            map[row][col] = 'O';
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving the *address* of `move` to `scanf()`:

```
scanf(" %c", &move);
```

`scanf()` needs a *destination* (address) specifying where to write the character scanned/read.  You are giving it whatever garbage value happens to be in `move`.  It is using this value as an address and trying to write your character there.  Since it is writing to an invalid memory location, it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Like forgetting `;`, forgetting `&` in `scanf` is one of the most common mistakes in C programming.

And you forgot `&` for `move` in `scanf`.

Look into your code, I believe that you have already known the reason why need to pass address to `scanf`

But in case you haven't, you could refer this with high quality accepted answer
[Why scanf must take the address of operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893615/why-scanf-must-take-the-address-of-operator)