# Why does this code print a number that isn't my maximum?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C, and I'm trying to create a program that calculate an array's maximum, using input from keyboard. I don't understand why this code prints `4203785`. I think the algorithm is right. Can someone help me?

```
  int calcola_massimo(int vettore[], int size) {

        int max = vettore[0];
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < size; i++ ){

            if(vettore[i] > max){
                max = vettore[i];
            }
        }

        return max;
    }


    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        int array[10];
        int j;
        int max;

        for(j = 0; j< SIZE; j++){
            printf("Inserire valore n. %d \n", j+1);
            scanf("%d", array);
        }

        max = calcola_massimo(array, SIZE);
        printf("Il valore massimo e' : %d", max);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You're scanning the value into the *first* element of the array, not to the `j`th.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &array[j]);`

Comment: Change it to `scanf("%d", &array[j])`. Also assign `array` to like this - `int array[10] = {0};`

Comment: or `scanf("%d", array + j);` and also do `int array[SIZE];` instead of `int array[10];`

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. Can you can you explain, why i need to use "&" before array[j]?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893615/why-scanf-must-take-the-address-of-operator

Answer (score 2):

For starters it would be better to declare the array like

```
int array[SIZE];
```

As for the loop then you have to write either

```
scanf("%d", array + j );
```

or

```
scanf("%d", &array[j] );
```

Otherwise you always enter `array[0]`. All other elements of the array are not initialized.

It would be better to define the function itself the following way

```
int * calcola_massimo( const int vettore[], size_t size ) 
{
    const int *max = vettore;
    size_t i;

    for ( i = 1; i < size; i++  )
    {
        if ( *max < vettore[i] ) max = vettore + i;
    }

    return ( int * )max;
}
```

because nothing prevents the user to pass size equal to 0. Your original function in this case will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Cancel all previous comment - you have a good innovative solution.

Comment: @chux What do you mean?

Comment: "Cancel all previous comment" --> My previous comments - which you _may_ have seen, incorrectly reported a problem in your fine answer.