# C Program crashes at For Loop

Tags: c, crash

I'm new to C programming (I have some very basic experience with programming via vb.NET), and I'm attempting to write a program for the Project Euler Problem #1.
https://projecteuler.net/problem=1

## Algorithm

The challenge requires the programmer to find the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 (inclusive) below 1000 (I used intInput to allow the user to enter an integer in place of 1000).

My current solution takes the input, and decrements it by 1 until (intInput - n) % 3 = 0, that is, until the next nearest multiple of 3 under the input integer is found.

The program then cycles through all integers from 1 to ((intInput - n) / 3), adding each integer to the sum of the previous integers, so long as the current integer is not a multiple of 5, in which case, it is skipped.

The resultant sum is then stored in intThreeMultiplier.

The above process is then repeated, using 5 in place of 3 to find the highest multiple of 5 under intInput, and then cycles through integers 1 to ((intInput - n) / 5), not skipping multiples of 3 this time, and stores the sum in intFiveMultiplier.

The output sum is then calculated via sum = (3 * intThreeMultiplier) + (5 * intFiveMultiplier).

## The Problem

Whenever I compile and run my code, the user is allowed to input an integer, and then the program crashes. I have determined that the cause has something to do with the first For loop, but I can't figure out what it is.

I have commented out everything following the offending code fragment.

## Source Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int intInput = 0;   /*Holds the target number (1000 in the challenge statement.)*/
    int n = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int intThreeMultiplier = 1;
    int intFiveMultiplier = 1;

    printf("Please enter a positive integer.\n");
    scanf("%d",intInput);

    for( ; (((intInput - n) % 3) != 0) ; n++)  
        {}

    /*for(; count <= ((intInput - n) / 3); count++)
        {
            if ((count % 5) != 0)
            {
                intThreeMultiplier += count;
            }
        }

    count = 0;
    for(n = 0 ; ((intInput - n) % 5) != 0 ; n++)
    {}

    for(; count <= ((intInput - n) / 5) ; count++)
    {
        intFiveMultiplier += count;
    }

    int sum = (3 * intThreeMultiplier) + (5 * intFiveMultiplier);
    printf("The sume of all multiples of 3 or 5 (inclusively) under %d is %d.",intInput, sum);*/
}
```

This is my first time posting on StackOverflow, so I apologize in advance if I have broken any of the rules for asking questions, and would appreciate any feedback with respect to this.

In addition, I am extremely open to any suggestions regarding coding practices, or any rookie mistakes I've made with C.

Thanks!

Comment: The first loop can not be able to crash unless you have a very buggy compiler generating faulty code. Have you tried running the program in a debugger to catch the crash in action, and then locate where it actually happen?

Comment: Why have you commented out most of the code?

Comment: Why do you need 2 loops? Just use 1 loop, and when the current number is a multiple of 3 or 5 add it to the total.

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid **and** deprecated signature. The minimum correct signature is `int main(void)` for hosted environments (you have one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d",intInput);
```

might be

```
scanf("%d", &intInput);  // note the ampersand
```

`scanf` need the address the variable where the content is to be stored. [Why scanf must take the address of operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893615/why-scanf-must-take-the-address-of-operator)

For debugging only, print the input to verify that the input is accepted correctly, something like

```
printf("intInput = %d\n", intInput);
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks! Now I just need to work on the algorithm itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need when you are inputting `intInput` you should use:

```
 scanf("%d", &intInput);
```

Because `scanf()` need as an argument of a pointer to your variable. You are doing this by just putting the & sign before your int.

In addition I think that you should double check your algorithm, because you are summing up some numbers more than once. :)