# Program with array to find a sum in c

Tags: c, arrays

I was thinking of a `code` to find the sum of numbers.

So i wrote bellow `code` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i,s=0,a[100];
    printf("enter number of numbers");
    scanf("%d",n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    s=0;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {s=s+a[i];}
    printf("sum is%d\n",s);
}
```

But in the output it shows segmentation `error` . I.e.[image]

So whats the mistake?

Comment: `scanf("%d",n);` It should be `scanf("%d", &n)`

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings.

Comment: @chux anyway to do that in onlinegdb compiler?  Itll be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why scanf must take the address of operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893615/why-scanf-must-take-the-address-of-operator)

Comment: @user187604 I am not familiar with onlinegdb compiler.  It appears to be a weak compiler though lacking control over warnings - you get what you pay for.

Comment: @chux this is a pain for mobile users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this line:

```
scanf("%d",n);
```

should be replaced by

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

**Explanation:**

`scanf()` reads data from `stdin` according to format and store data in the location pointed by next additional argument. this case, format is `%d` means we want to read an integer number and this integer number will be stored in the location of `n`. The `&` operator is to get the location of a variable in C.

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

***The reason :***

You MUST put `&` in front of the variable used in `scanf`. The reason why will become clear once you learn about pointers. It is easy to forget the `&` sign, and when you forget it your program will almost always crash when you run it.

***Examples :***

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
printf("%d %d", a, b);
```

As `a` and `b` above are two variable and each has their own address assigned but instead of `a` and `b`, we send the address of `a` and `b` respectively. The reason is, `scanf()` needs to modify values of `a` and `b` and but they are local to `scanf()`. So in order to reflect changes in the variable `a` and `b` of the main function, we need to pass addresses of them. We cannot simply pass them by value.
But in case of `printf` function as we are only going to print the values of the variables in output console, there are no changes going to be made in variable a and b’s values. So it is not required to send their addresses.

Comment: The crash can be prevented in every case if the variable is initialized while declaring.